# What is the variance of an MLE for a trinomial distribution?

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood

I am playing with the following trinomial (multinomial) distribution which can get values (a,b,c) with the probabilities: $(\theta^2, 2\theta(1-\theta), (1-\theta)^2)$.

Say I have n observations from this distribution, then it is easy to show that the MLE for estimating $\theta$ is: $\hat \theta_{MLE} = {2\#a+ \#b \over 2n}$. However, I am trying to find the variance of this MLE, and keep getting a negative variance (which means I have a mistake somewhere, but I can't find where).

(EDIT: the correct answer is marked below :) )

Comment: Those are [*Hardy-Weinberg proportions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle) for two allele, single locus genotype frequencies.

Comment: Defining your slot(?) notation -- 2#a + #b -- would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I believe this is now correct

Let $X_a$ and $X_b$ be the counts in categories $a$ and $b$. Consider first the case for a single observation ($n=1$):

- $\text{Var}(X_a) = \theta^2(1-\theta^2)$
- $\text{Var}(X_b) = 2\theta(1-\theta)(1-2\theta(1-\theta))$
- Since the categories are mutually exclusive, $E(X_aX_b)=0$, so $\text{Cov}(X_a,X_b)=-E(X_a)E(X_b)=-2\theta^3(1-\theta)$.

Hence $Var(2X_a+X_b)=4Var(X_a)+Var(X_b)+4Cov(X_a,X_b)\\
\hspace{2.96cm}=4\theta^2(1-\theta^2)+2\theta(1-\theta)(1-2\theta(1-\theta))-8\theta^3(1-\theta)\\
\hspace{2.96cm}=2\theta(1-\theta)\,[2\theta(1+\theta)+(1-2\theta(1-\theta))-4\theta^2]\\
\hspace{2.96cm}=2\theta(1-\theta)$

Hence, (since the variance for $n$ independent observations is $n$ times the variance of one), $Var(2X_a+X_b)=2n\theta(1-\theta)$.

Hence $\text{Var}(\frac{1}{2n}(2X_a+X_b))  = \frac{1}{4n^2}2n\theta(1-\theta)=\frac{1}{2n}\theta(1-\theta)$.

This is non-negative for $0\leq\theta\leq 1$, and simulations agree with this answer.

Comment: Thanks Glen, I see my problem was with E(X_a X_b). Could you please help me understand why it is 0? (and/or what is the distribution of X_a | X_b ? ) - thinking of this more: I think it shouldn't be 0 (I mean, both counts have a non-zero probability of both getting a positive number)

Comment: Tal - this the advantage of looking at a single observation first. One observation can only be in one category at a time, so at least one of the counts is necessarily 0, so the product in that case is 0. When you have multiple observations, the covariance must be the sum of covariances. The expectation of a product of counts won't be zero in that case, but that doesn't make the argument invalid - the covariance of the sum must still be the sum of the covariances of the one-observation cases.

Comment: Well, let's say we have n=2. Then There is some chance of there being 1 a and 1 b. Hence, I suspect, E above should not be 0.

Comment: I (think I) found the error. Typing it now and soon will put it online.

Comment: Answer posted - if you have a handy simulation - could you please have a look to see if I got it right?

Comment: You still need to fix $E[X_a * X_b]$

Comment: No, I don't. That argument has always been 100% correct. The argument doesn't make the claim that $E(X_aX_b)=0$ at any time other than when $n=1$ (I don't even know what $E(X_aX_b)=0$ is in the $n>1$ case, because it's irrelevant to the argument). It certainly is correct when $n=1$. Then it uses simple properties of variance to compute the $n>1$ variance from the $n=1$ case. It's a standard trick for multinomials.

Comment: I see what you are saying (thanks :) ). BTW, it is $2n\left[ {n - 1} \right]\left( {1 - \theta } \right){\theta ^3}$ for the general case (and indeed for n=1, it goes to 0).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the discussion with Glen, I realized that (assume ${X_a}$ is the number of a's and ${X_b}$ is the count of b's):

$${X_a}|{X_b} \sim B\left( {n - {X_b},{p_L} = \frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{{\theta ^2} + {{\left( {1 - \theta } \right)}^2}}}} \right)$$

Hence:

$$E\left( {{X_a}|{X_b}} \right) = \left( {n - {X_b}} \right)\frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{{\theta ^2} + {{\left( {1 - \theta } \right)}^2}}}{\rm{ }}$$

Making:

$${\mathop{\rm cov}} \left( {{X_a},{X_b}} \right) =  - 2n\left( {1 - \theta } \right){\theta ^3}$$

Leading to:

$$V\left( {{{\hat \theta }_{MLE}}} \right) = \frac{{\theta \left( {1 - \theta } \right)}}{{2n}}$$

:)

Comment: Defining $X_L$ and $X_M$ would be helpful.

Comment: If $X_L$ is the count in $a$, your answer agrees with my simulations.

Comment: wolfies - done. Glen_b - cool :)

Comment: I finally spotted my own remaining error as well

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ one can easily check that $2X_a+X_b$ has the binomial distribution on $\{0,1,2\}$ with success probability $\theta$. Then the expectation and the variance easily follow for any $n$. More precisely, one also deduces that $2X_a+X_b$ has the binomial distribution on $\{0,\ldots,2n\}$ with success probability $\theta$.)

In fact, you can see the model as the one for the following experiment. Let $Y_i \sim Bin(2, \theta)$ modeling one observation. Then you observe $f(Y_i)$ with $f(0)=c, f(1)=b, f(2)=a$. The sum $Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n \sim Bin(2n,\theta)$ is a sufficient statistic and the mle of $\theta$ is $\frac{Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n}{2n}$, and $Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n = 0 \times \#c + 1\times \#b + 2\times \#a$.

Comment: @TalGalili Updated answer to show how to derive the mle.